# Java socket reading and writeing hex code

Tags: java, serversocket

I'm working on a project and i want to comunicate with a device. I made a socket connection with the device, the connection works but the device is sending me the message: 0xd7d0 and i have to write that message back. It's a keep alive message. I'm haveing trouble reading and sending back that message. 
here's the code i've writen so far:

```
package Server;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Server {

    public static ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1234);

            while (true) {
                ServerThread serverThread = new ServerThread(serverSocket.accept());
                serverThread.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}

package Server;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ServerThread extends Thread {

    public Socket socket;
    public BufferedReader in;
    public PrintWriter out; 
    public ByteBuffer buf;
    int count;


    public ServerThread (Socket socket) {
        try {
            this.socket = socket;
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ServerThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                count = in.read();
                buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(100);
                buf.put((byte) count);
                buf.flip();
                out.println(buf);

                String line = in.readLine();
                System.out.println(line);




            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ServerThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is that you mix different styles of network data exchange. First, what format are messages in? Are they characters in some encoding, or some binary data? In the first case, you should not use Buffer to read message in, but read and write using `in` and `out` character streams you created already. In the second case, you have 2 options: read and write with socket and byte streams, or with channels from `java.nio.channels` and `Buffer`s. To write back a message in a buffer, you can use

```
     buf.flip();
     buffer.position(buffer.limit());
```

Comment: thank you! there are 2 kinds of data, the first one is hex 0xd7d0 and the second is string.

Comment: hy again, well the string looks like this: 2030000000,20121207195256,25.650723,44.982666,0,291,269.0,0,11,0.0,13,0.01,0.01,1,00,00,10b4 and the keep alive looke like: 0xD7 0xD0, the device connects to the server sends a message like 0xD7 0xD0 and i have to send it back to open the comunication and the rest of the transmision is just string. Thank you!

Comment: When I ask about encoding, I mean Ascii, utf-8 and so on. When I ask about lengh, is the length encoded as integer before the string, or null byte signals the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
while (true) {
    ServerThread serverThread = new ServerThread(serverSocket.accept());
    serverThread.start();
}
```

doesn't look right. You're looping and creating a new thread repeatedly (which will consume resources and create an enormous number of threads). You should simply create that thread once. If your program is doing nothing else then a new thread may be superfluous.

Comment: This looks right. This is to create new thread for each incoming connection request.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i will make it write, but i'm havin trouble reading and writeing back to the device. any ideas?

Comment: search in Google "java example echo server"